# How do I add qt5 to my openembedded build?

Tags: linux, qt, package, openembedded, bitbake

I have an OpenEmbedded-core build environment that was set up for me to build. I was looking through it, trying to understand how it works, and I found what I believe to be the list of packages that's built.

```
~/ccf/oe-core/meta$ ls
classes      recipes-bsp           recipes-gnome       recipes-qt       site
conf         recipes-connectivity  recipes-graphics    recipes-rt
COPYING.MIT  recipes-core          recipes-kernel      recipes-sato
files        recipes-devtools      recipes-lsb4        recipes-support
lib          recipes-extended      recipes-multimedia  recipes.txt
```

I think these are all built by my project and I'm also under the impression that anything new added here will be added to all built projects. Now my projects needs Qt5, when I look under the `recipes-qt` directory I see:

```
~/ccf/oe-core/meta/recipes-qt$ ls
images  meta  packagegroups  qt4  qt4-graphics-system  qt-apps  qt-demo
```

So clearly qt4 is being built here, but I want to add qt5.

My two questions:

1. Are my assumptions correct so far?
2. What's the right way to go about adding a new qt5 package? I'm not sure if this is something I can "pull" from some OE project or if I need to do this from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than starting from scratch have you tried [meta-qt5](https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5)?

Comment: meta-qt5 is indeed the best route, it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at `recipes-qt/qt-demo` first.